# Why am I unable to create/checkout this branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I am trying to create a local Git branch, but it is not working.
Here are the commands I am using:

```sh
tablet:edit11$ git checkout -b edit_11
Switched to a new branch 'edit_11'
tablet:edit11$ git checkout edit_11
error: pathspec 'edit_11' did not match any file(s) known to git.
tablet:edit11$ git branch
tablet:edit11$
```

What's going on?

Comment: What does `git branch -a` say?

Comment: `git branch -a` outputs nothing.

Comment: @Jubobs I have changed the accepted answer.
I need to learn git..
Can you suggest me a good source?

Comment: @KulwantSingh You can start by reading the first few chapters of the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/doc). Stack Overflow is also a good source of information, when you have a particular question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You successfully created and "switched to" a branch called `edit_11` when you ran

```
git checkout -b edit_11
```

However, everything (incl. an empty `git branch` output) indicates that you have just initialised your repository and have yet made to make an initial commit. If there is no commit, branches have nothing useful to point at and there is nothing to check out.

Therefore, when you run

```
git checkout edit_11
```

you get the following error,

```
error: pathspec 'edit_11' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

even though branch `edit_11` does exists.

---

The problem can be reproduced as follows:

```bash
$ mkdir testgit
$ cd testgit
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /xxxx/testgit/.git/
$ git checkout -b edit_11
Switched to a new branch 'edit_11'
$ git checkout edit_11
error: pathspec 'edit_11' did not match any file(s) known to git.
$ git branch
$
```

After you make a first commit on branch `edit_11`, `git checkout edit_11` will not longer throw any error. Note that, in this example,  `git checkout edit_11` is a no-op because the *current* branch already is `edit_11`.

```bash
$ printf foo > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m "add README"
[edit_11 (root-commit) 90fe9c1] add README
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git branch
* edit_11
$ git checkout edit_11 
Already on 'edit_11'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line creates the new branch and moves you to that branch.
You don't need to do anything more.
Just use:

```
git checkout -b edit_11
```

Comment: I created some files, committed and pushed to remote repository.
It worked.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the answer to the problem.

Comment: @Jubobs Why not? He wants to create a new local branch and move to that branch.

Comment: @JuanAntonioDelgado `git checkout -b edit_11` is the first command that the OP reported to run. Running it a second time won't solve the problem. No; the error is thrown because no commit exists yet, and there is nothing to check out. See my answer.

Comment: @Jubobs You're right. I thought that the repository was previously initialized properly.

Comment: @JuanAntonioDelgado It was initialised properly. The only problem is that, without any commit, `git checkout <branch>` won't work.