# Should I create my own branch named master?

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I can't tell what my current branch is. Is it `master`?
If so, why doesn't `git branch` does show any information?

```
adminuser@Admin MINGW64 /c/Project/Repo/MyPortal (master)
$ git branch

adminuser@Admin MINGW64 /c/Project/Repo/MyPortal (master)
$ git branch -a

adminuser@Admin MINGW64 /c/Project/Repo/MyPortal (master)
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

adminuser@Admin MINGW64 /c/Project/Repo/MyPortal (master)
$
```

Why can I not successfully run `git checkout master`? Should I run `git checkout -b master` instead?

Comment: There is a `master` branch (as indicated by the context of your prompt) but it doesn't point to anything useful, because you have yet to make make your first commit. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109985/why-am-i-unable-to-create-checkout-this-branch

Comment: What result do you get when you try **git branch**, do you see master listed in the result?

Comment: @Jubobs, thank you, after I commit as you suggested, now I can see master.